# Запрет доступа к папке

Tags: .htaccess

На сервере лежит папка, надо запретить в нее доступ всем, кроме самого сервера. Я пишу следующее:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from local.
```

При таком раскладе налагается запрет на доступ и даже скрипты, находящиеся на самом сервере не могут обратиться к файлам в папке. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: а что такое `local.`? может быть, имелся в виду `localhost`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - да, это локалхост, но в инструкциях по .htaccess пишут именно так.

Comment: попробуйте всё-таки заменить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не работает. Видимо что-то не так в записи правил. Только пока не понял, что именно.

Comment: 1. если закомментировать эти три строки, скриты работают нормально? 2. каким именно образом скрипты обращаются к файлам в этом каталоге?

Comment: кстати, *apache* у вас какой версии?

Comment: а правила обрабатываются разве не в порядке следования?! не должно ли быть Allow from localhost первым?!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin скрипт обращается к файлу в папке при помощи require_once или include, так же есть подключения такие как при подключении css файлов.

Comment: 1. *include* — у меня была гипотеза, что вы обращаетесь как-нибудь вроде `include('http://my.host.name/php.scritp')` (с указанием имени/ip-адреса сервера). 2. *как при подключении css файлов* — css-файлы не «подключаются», об их существовании лишь сообщается браузеру. и браузер делает http-запросы уже к этим файлам. если они в «закрытом» для внешнего мира каталоге, то http-сервер ничего браузеру не отдаст.

Comment: попробуйте ещё для надёжности добавить ip-адрес loopback-интерфейса (в сокращённом до первого октета виде): `allow from localhost 127.`. обратите внимание на точку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
Allow from localhost
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте заменить `local.` на `localhost`:

```
Allow from localhost
```